# Proteus microcontroller 8051 output wrong signal with frequency 12 MHz

Tags: assembly, 8051

How to apply this description for my 8051 microcontroller?

- Transmission speed: V_pd = 62500 baud;
- clock frequency of the quartz resonator: f_CLK = 12 MHz;
- to use the UART module for sharing;
- transmission mode - asynchronous;
- data word size - 8 digits;
- use parity check;
- number of stop bits - 1;
- transmission bytes: 01100010b;
- ASCII - receive symbol - g,
- SMOD = 1.

Schematic Capture

[image]

and such code for 8051

```
;====================================================================
; Main.asm file generated by New Project wizard
;
; Created:  
; Processor: AT89C51
; Compiler:  ASEM-51 (Proteus)
;====================================================================

$NOMOD51
$INCLUDE (8051.MCU)

;====================================================================
; DEFINITIONS
;====================================================================

;====================================================================
; VARIABLES
;====================================================================

;====================================================================
; RESET and INTERRUPT VECTORS
;====================================================================

      ; Reset Vector
      org   0000h
      jmp   Start

;====================================================================
; CODE SEGMENT
;====================================================================

      org   0100h
Start:  
      ; Write your code here
Loop:   

MOV P1, #11111111b  ;
            ; 
            ; 
            ;  
CLR TCON.6      ; 
CLR IE.3        ;
CLR IE.4        ; 
MOV TH1,#11111111b      ; 
            ; 
MOV SCON,#11010000b ; 
MOV A, PCON     ; A <- PCON
ANL A, #01111111b   ; A <- A & 01111111b
MOV PCON, A     ; PCON <- A
MOV TMOD,#00100000b ;
SETB TCON.6     
CIN: JNB RI,CIN     
MOV P2,#67h;,SBUF       ;
CLR RI          ; 

            ;       
MOV P2, #00h        ; 
MOV A, P1       ; 
MOV P2, A       ;

JB PSW.0, TransmitedNumberIsOdd
JNB PSW.0, TransmiteNumberIsEven

TransmitedNumberIsOdd:
SETB SCON.3     ; 
jmp Transmit

TransmiteNumberIsEven:
jmp Transmit

Transmit:
MOV SBUF,#62h;, A       ;
COUT: JNB TI, COUT  ; 
            ; 
CLR TI          ; 

CLR SCON.3      ; 
JB SCON.2, RecievedNumberIsOdd
JNB SCON.2, RecievedNumberIsEven

RecievedNumberIsOdd:
MOV SBUF, #11111111b    ;
Odd: JNB  TI, Odd   ; 
            ; 
CLR TI          ; 
jmp Loop

RecievedNumberIsEven:
MOV SBUF, #00000000b    ; 
Even: JNB  TI, Even ; 
            ; 
CLR TI          ; 

jmp Loop

;====================================================================
      END
```

[image] - in this image is how it has to be in 
digital oscilloscope and virtual terminal with frequency 6Mhz and baud rate 110

proteus project: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sut0LtCkS8FWwoV0OHSX1DOVpofnLhBv/view?usp=sharing

[image] - my incorrect output in 
digital oscilloscope and virtual terminal with frequency 12Mhz and baud rate 62500

My proteus project:
(file included (https://drive.google.com/file/d/15eZg-abC3D0JzOlOkteOTFVmLKMddLYL/view?usp=sharing))

Comment: You are going to have to do a bit better than that.   There are numerous toolchains, ides, jtags & ice's available for the 8051.  Without a cursory explanation of your environment, nobody will be able to help you.   Also, links are somewhat frowned upon, many having lived the goatse.cx experience.

Comment: Title says: "not working correctly", the body of the question does not mention what exactly is incorrect.

Comment: Ok i will do that another way

Comment: Please read "[ask]". The most needed information you should provide is: What do you expect, and what do you get? Please [edit] your question, don't comment down here. You could also explain how much you understood from the scope recording and why you think it's wrong. Also, you might like to reduce your problem to a [example]. In example, we don't need all that even/odd stuff if it's a wrong baudrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to make some changes in code

setb ACC.7 insted of ANL A,#01111111b

8051 Baud Rate Calculator
http://www.keil.com/products/c51/baudrate.asp

buttons

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Q0lC.png)

When you click start vsm debbuging
add stop point and get signal on digital oscilloscope.
Then rotate this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTP5j.png)

and get signal.

final output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vY3Mv.png)